# How to perform simple multiplication using populate in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on add to cart feature and I'm trying to calculate the subtotal of all products in the cart. In my Cart collection, I have an array of product refs and other attributes that are selected by user. The price of a particular product variation is stored in the Product collection. When I query Cart collection, I want to multiply the selected quantity by product price to get subtotal.

What I've tried is to use populate() to get the variations field but I can't figure out how to filter only the variation selected by user. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you guys.

```
await Cart.findOne({ user: userId }).populate({
      path: 'products.product',
      model: 'Product',
      select: 'variations',
      match: { colour: { $eq: 'Black' }, size: { $eq: 'M' } }, 
    });
```

```
const Cart = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
  products: [
    {
      product: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Product' }, 
      colour: { type: String, required: true },
      size: { type: String, required: true },
      quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
    },
  ]
});

const Product = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    variations: [
      {
        price: { type: Decimal128, required: true },
        quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
        colour: String,
        size: String,
      },
    ],
  },
);
```

**Edit**

Example Cart document:

```
{ user: 605dcvaddee2a83299c7482b,
  products: [{
    product: { 
     variations: [
      { colour: Black, size: S, price: 45, quantity: 100 },
      { colour: Black, size: M, price: 50, quantity: 100 }, // need this price
      { colour: Black, size: L, price: 60, quantity: 100 },  
      ]
    },
    colour: 'Black', //selected by user
    size: 'M', //selected by user
    quantity: 20 //selected by user
  }]
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
{ 
  user: 605dcvaddee2a83299c7482b,
  products: [{
    product: { 
     variations: { colour: Black, size: M, price: 50, quantity: 100 }
    },
    colour: 'Black', //selected by user
    size: 'M', //selected by user
    quantity: 20 //selected by user
  }],
  subtotal: 1000
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example `Cart` document?

Comment: Hi @programmerRaj, i've edited with an example.

Comment: Do you need hte subtotal to be retrived the the query, or is it fine if you calculate the subtotal after getting the result?

Comment: If possible I want to perform the calculation with the query

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please expand your question by showing the expected result as well as the result you are not satisfied with. Possibly show any log file passages where the error message is contained.  Last but not least, show us your efforts that were unsuccessful.